# how to get the moore neighbourhood using index of a vector

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix in `Rcpp` (`C++` for `R`) which is stored in column order in memory. Ie, it looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Now, I have a single `for` loop that runs from `i = 1` to `25` (bear in mind, it is all zero based, but here I am just saying one for convenience).

For every element of the matrix, I want its Moore neighbourhood. This is easy for the elements that are not on the edge. So if our selected index is `idx` and the size of the square matrix is `nrow` then we have

```
leftmid = idx - nrow 
lefttop = (idx - nrow) - 1
leftbot = (idx - nrow) + 1

rightmid = idx + nrow
righttop = (idx + nrow) - 1
rightbot = (idx + nrow) + 1

midtop = idx - 1
midbot = idx + 1
```

But i cant figure out how to deal with the edge cases. For example, if `idx = 3`, then i want the neighbours:

```
leftmid = 23
lefttop = 22
leftbot = 24

rightmid = 8
righttop = 7
rightbot = 9

midtop = 2
midbot = 4
```

It's a little bit more complicated at the corner cases as well. My goal here is to reduce time. I am currently running my program with a double for loop which works, but is slower than reasonable. I want to change it into a single `for` loop to improve performance.

Edit: I realized the `left` and `right` boundaries can be obtained by modulus. So `3 - 5 %% 25 = 23`. But I still have the top and bottom edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're interested in "cyclic" boundary conditions, where the matrix has a toroidal topology, i.e. the top wraps around to the bottom and the right wraps around to the left.

It might be easier to iterate with four loops, one each over the row and column, and then one each over the row and column of the neighborhood. Something like this should work:

```
int mooreNeighbors[3][3];
int nRows = 5;
int nCols = 5;

// Loop over the rows and columns of the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; ++j) {

        // Loop over the cyclic Moore neighborhood
        for (int mnI = 0; mnI < 3; ++mnI) {
            for (int mnJ = 0; mnJ < 3; ++mnJ) {

                // Sub-matrix indices
                int subI = (i - mnI - 1) % nRows;
                int subJ = (j - mnJ - 1) % nCols;

                // Index into column-dominant matrix
                int idx = subI + subJ*nRows;

                mooreNeighbors[mnI][mnJ] = matrix[idx]; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried compiling this, but it should be close to correct and clear enough to correct any mistakes.  Think of it as pseudo-code.

Also, I'm preferring clarity over optimality.  For example, you don't have to do everything in the inner-most loop.